# Grouping logs in CircleCI

Tags: circleci

Some CI providers have a way of grouping logs into collapsible segments, making reading long log outputs easier. For example, GitHub has something like this:

```
::group::{section title}
{logs that should be grouped}
::endgroup::
```

[image]

Does CircleCI provide something like this?